# Error:strptime() argument 1 must be str, not floatと表示される。

Tags: python, python3

機械学習初心者の学生です。
以下のコードを走らせたところ、TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not float と表示されました。 strptimeのstrへの型変換が必要かと思いつつも、うまく修正ができません。

```
import datetime

pp = df["DATE"]
tmp = []

for i in range(len(pp)):
    #print(pp[i])
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(pp[i], "%Y/%m/%d")
    tmp.append(d.weekday())
```

ご教示頂けますと幸いです。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ２点ほど (1) df は pandas.DataFrame() という認識で合ってますでしょうか？。(2) df['DATE'] には どのようなデータが入っているのかを数行でもよいので提示していただけないでしょうか

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。(1)おっしゃるとおり、pandasのデータフレームです。(2)一つのセルに2018/4/1が入っており、すぐ下のセルには2018/4/1、それが計24回続いた後、2018/4/2に移ります。（隣接するセルで一時間ごとの時間を記載しています。）

Comment: であれば DATE列の型は問題なく"文字列(Ojject)型"か"DateTime型"になっている筈なのですが。何故 "not float"と出てるのでしょうか？ とりあえず (1) print(df['DATE'].dtype) にて DATE列の型を確認 (2)DATE列に 数値データが混入していないかの確認 をしてみてくさい。
あと、最終的に行いたい内容は "文字列型(Object型)のデータを Datetime型のデータに変換して曜日データを取得したい"ということで良いのですよね。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。(2)DATE列に一部数値データが含まれており、そちらを解決いたしました。大変お騒がせしました。（3)最終的に行いたい内容は "文字列型(Object型)のデータを Datetime型のデータに変換して曜日データを取得したい"ということでお間違えございません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

不具合は既に解決してそうなのですが、とりあえず

現在ループにより `datetime.strptime()` の処理を行っておりますが、pandasには `pandas.to_datetime()`という非常に強力な 時系列データへの変換関数が用意されておりますので、こちらを使うことで

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
```

と簡単に **DATE列**を`文字列型`から`Datetime型`に変換することができます。（さすがにfloat型とstr型が混ざっていたら無理ですが・・）

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html

また、**DATE列**を`Datetime型`にすることにより `Series.dt()` という`Datetime型`のデータへの**Accessor**が使用できますので、曜日の取得は

```
df['DATE'].dt.weekday
```

のように行うことができますので、合わせて覚えておくと良いかと思います。

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.html

---

ということで、以下は動作サンプルです

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': ['2018/4/1','2018/4/2','2018/4/3']})
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df['Month'] = df['DATE'].dt.month
df['Day'] = df['DATE'].dt.day
df['Weekday'] = df['DATE'].dt.weekday
print(df)
#        DATE  Month  Day  WeekDay
#0 2018-04-01      4    1        6
#1 2018-04-02      4    2        0
#2 2018-04-03      4    3        1
```